# Changing the 'Initial State' of a flow's configuration from 'stopped' to 'started'?

Tags: mule

How do you change the 'Initial State' of a flow's configuration from 'stopped' to 'started'?  I have a flow that I want to turn on only when a certain condition is met at startup.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is 2 ways to do in runtime:-
1) Use Groovy component to start a flow :-

```
<scripting:component>
    <scripting:script engine="groovy">
        muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct('targetFlow').start()
    </scripting:script>
</scripting:component>
```

where **targetFlow** is the name of the flow you need to start

or Second way is :-
Use a expression component to start a flow ... here **flow1** is the name of the flow to start :-

```
<expression-component>

    app.registry.flow1.start();

  </expression-component>
```

Comment: Additionally, the expression for the Groovy component can be reduced to just this: targetFlow.start()